# Euler Project #3 Largest prime factor timeout

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded, primes

I have been recently trying my hands on Euler's Project through HackerRank and got stuck with project #3 where you have to find the [Largest Prime Factor.](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler003)

**Question:** *The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
What is the largest prime factor of a given number N?*

I have written two different codes which both work for the first four problems in HackerRank but timeout on the last two. Please let me know how I can optimize my code further so that the timeout doesn't occur.

**Code #1**

```
for a in range(int(input())):
    n = int(input())
    b = n//2
    i=1
    if b%2==1:
        i+=1
    max=1
    while b > 2:
        if n%b==0:
            isprime = True
            for c in range(2,int(b**0.5)+1):
                if b%c==0:
                    isprime = False
                    break;
            if isprime:
                max = b
                break;
        b-=i
    if max==1:
        max=n
    print(max)
```

This one tries to find the first largest numbers which can divide a particular number and then tries to find whether it is a prime.

**Code #2**

```
for a in range(int(input())):
    n = int(input())
    num = n
    b = 2
    max=1
    while n > 1 and b < (num//2)+1:
        if n%b==0:
            n//=b
            max=b
        b+=1
    if max==1:
        max=n
    print(max)
```

This basically tries to find the last largest factor by multiple division.

Comment: Please fix your indentation. The easiest way to post code is to paste it into the question editor, highlight it, and press Ctrl-K to mark it as a code block.

Comment: Who are `a` and `b` and why haven't you used more sensible names instead? Can you tell us more about your approach?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me your second code example is wrong. You divide out only one prime factor and moving on testing for divisibility. If you enter, say: `8`, it finds 2, divides it out, which gives 4, and will find 4 as largest prime that divides 8.

You have a lot of redundant tests, stepping `b` by one.

Consider this:
Write any positive number `n` as `n = m + 6*q` (`q` may be 0). Except for the prime numbers 2 and 3: If `m` is divisible by 2, then so is `n` (because 6 is divisible by 2). If `m` is divisible by 3, then so is `n` (again, because 6 is divisible by 3). The only chances for `n` to be prime is, if `m` is 1 or 5. Not all of those numbers are prime, but if it is prime, it will be 1 or 5 modulo 6.

That will add a few lines of code, to explicitly test for primes 2 and 3. But after that, it should speed up your algorithm. Just remember to divide out *all* powers of a prime before moving on. A single test could look like this:

```
n = int(input())
num = n
max = 1

if n % 2 == 0:
    max = 2
    while n % 2 == 0:
        n //= 2

if n % 3 == 0:
    max = 3
    while n % 3 == 0: 
        n //= 3

b = 5
inc = 2

while n != 1:
    if n % b==0:
        max = b
        while n % b == 0: 
            n //= b

    b += inc
    if inc == 2:
        inc = 4
    else:
        inc = 2
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Please don't answer off-topic questions. As long as the indentation in the original question is off (and thus the code broken), the question is considered off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

It may be more optimal to use the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) because it may reuse calculations better than the given approaches. This would be a bottom-up approach rather than a top-down approach but it is a very efficient bottom-up approach.

You just need to take the extra step where for each entry you find to be prime, you check if it is a factor of the given number. You also have a early stopping condition - the prime factor must be <=sqrt(N). So you need a sieve for 1 ... sqrt(N)

Note that there are ways to work with a segmented sieve, to minimise the amount of memory used at once.